# Warning: missing argument error on putting stores in database

Tags: php

On my website , i want to register a user.

My HTML is:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <p>If you already have an account, please login</p>
            <div class="styled_select">
                <select name="title">
                    <option value="mr">Mr</option>
                    <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
                    <option value="miss">Miss</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required><br>
            <div class="styled_select">
                <select name="sex" required>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" required><br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" required> Agree to terms and conditions. <br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="keep_informed"> Keep me informed on future promotions. <br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Register" class="submit_button"><br>
        </form>
```

My php function is:

```
class Register {

    public function register($title, $first_name, $last_name, $sex, $age, $email, $zipcode, $telephone, $keep_informed) {

        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
        $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($first_name);
        $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($sex);
        $sex = mysql_real_escape_string($age);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
        $zipcode = mysql_real_escape_string($zipcode);
        $telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($telephone);
        $keep_informed = mysql_real_escape_string($keep_informed);  

        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testbox_new', 'root', '');

        $sql = 'insert into users (title, first_name, last_name, sex, age, email, zipcode, telephone, keep_informed)
        values ("'.$title.'", "'.$first_name.'", 
        "'.$last_name.'", "'.$sex.'", 
        "'.$age.'", "'.$email.'", 
        "'.$zipcode.'", "'.$telephone.'", 
        "'.$keep_informed.'")';

        if ($dbh->exec($sql)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and i call the function with:

```
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['first_name']) 
                            && isset($_POST['last_name']) 
                            && isset($_POST['sex']) 
                            && isset($_POST['age']) 
                            && isset($_POST['email']) 
                            && isset($_POST['zipcode']) 
                            && isset($_POST['telephone'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['keep_informed'])) {
        $keep_informed = $_POST['keep_informed'];
    } else {
        $keep_informed = 0;
    }
    $register = new Register;
    $insert = $register->register($_POST['title'], $_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['sex'], $_POST['age'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['zipcode'], $_POST['telephone'], $keep_informed);
    if ($insert == true) {
        header ('location: index1.php');
    } else {
        echo 'somethings gone wrong';
    }

}
```

The errors i get are the following:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 2 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 3 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 4 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 5 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 6 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 7 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 8 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Warning: Missing argument 9 for Register::register(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 53 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: first_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: sex in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined variable: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: zipcode in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: keep_informed in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined variable: keep_informed in C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php on line 31
```

Is there anyone who knows what the problem is ?
I really can't figure it out!

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Thx!

Comment: SQL injection warning.

Comment: print out your variables, check if they are correctly set. Something has went wrong before posting your data to your function

Comment: Can you post the whole contents of the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\testbox\register.php` or at least everything from the top to the end of the function register?

Comment: @Technoh i just edited my post ;)

Comment: @BrechtSchepens - which is line 53? Is it `$register = new Register;`, or the following line?

Comment: Is it possible that the 'new Register' is calling your 'register' function as a constructor?

Comment: @ethrbunny - that's what I think. I assume the Register class doesn't have an explicit constructor, so when he's instantiating it, it's running `register()` as the constructor instead.

Comment: @andrewsi it is $regiser = new Register;

Comment: i renamed te funtion to register_user and now it works ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the line that's causing the issue:

```
$register = new Register;
```

Your Register class doesn't have an explicit constructor. When you instantiate the object, PHP is checking to see if there's an old-style constructor in there - that is, a method that has the same name as the class. And it does - your `register()` method is being called then.

To get around this, you can either add in a constructor method to your class, or re-name the register method.

You can see the details of how constructors work in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: Very obvious yet no one thought of it before you :) Did you have to try the code to see it?

Comment: I didn't think it was that obvious - I was looking at the code for a good few minutes wondering how it could be failing when it's explicitly passing in valid parameters before wondering if I was looking in the wrong place. I vaguely remembered the implicit constructor behaviour, so it was off to the manual :D